# Interior of a null set given the Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

So, my question is, given a set A so that it has a null measure given the Lebesgue measure, does it have any interior points?

I've been trying to find some counter-examples, but I can't find any. However, I haven't been successful in finding a prove of this either.

Answer (score 2):

Note that any non-empty open set has strictly positive Lebesgue measure (as $\lambda((a,b)) = b-a>0$ and all non-empty open sets are unions of non-trivial intervals). This in $\Bbb R$, but the same holds in $\Bbb R^n$.

So if $\operatorname{int}(A) \neq \emptyset$ we'd have

$$0 < \lambda(\operatorname{int}(A)) \le \lambda(A) =0$$

by monotonicity and we have contradiction. So $\operatorname{int}(A) = \emptyset$ when $A$ is a null set.

Comment: That's great, I didn't know about the first property you mentioned, thank you very much!

Comment: @TomásGuijaValiente A set with empty interior need not have measure $0$ though (consider the irrationals, e.g.)

Comment: *all non-empty open sets are unions of non-trivial intervals* --- Note that the weaker property "contains a non-trivial open interval", which is usually just the definition of a nonempty open set (or at least is a non-vacuous consequence of the definition of an open set in ${\mathbb R}),$ suffices here, as well as being more direct (since don't have logically go from union of one or more non-trivial intervals to contains a non-trivial interval).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro True, just some $r>0$ and $(x-r,x+r) \subseteq A$ for some $x \in \text{int}(A)$ suffices. I just wanted to accentuate the general principle (that Lebesgue measure is strictly positive, as it's called IIRC).

Comment: FYI, my comment was inspired by the OP's comment "I didn't know about ...", which I took for the union of intervals property (useful to know, but the OP didn't need to know it here), but maybe the OP's comment was was simply about nonempty open sets having positive measure (which, incidentally, suggests possibly losing the forest for the trees).